# Transfer data from sub-Sub to Function and back to main Sub

Tags: vbscript, catia

I'm trying to write code that fill array in Function and than return result to main Sub. But this Function called from another Sub (sub-Sub). To understand how this will work I tried go step by step. And wrote this code:

```
Sub CATMain()
    Dim val1
    Call WalkDownTree() 'Here I call Sub to walk down Product Tree in CATIA
    val1 = ParamTable(PartNumber, Name, Material, Texture, Color, Quantity)
    For i=0 To UBound(val1)
        MsgBox val1(i)
    Next

End Sub

Sub WalkDownTree() 'Simplified code of the walk down tree to understand data transfer
    PartNumber = "PartNumber"
    Name = "Name"
    Material = "Material"
    Texture = "Texture"
    Color = "Color"
    Quantity = 1
    Call ParamTable(PartNumber, Name, Material, Texture, Color, Quantity)
End Sub

Function ParamTable(PartNumber, Name, Material, Texture, Color, Quantity) 'Simplified array filing code. At original code I get all data from Part
    Dim BOMTable(6,1000)
    BOMTable(1,k) = PartNumber 
    BOMTable(2,k) = Name
    BOMTable(3,k) = Material
    BOMTable(4,k) = Texture
    BOMTable(5,k) = Color
    BOMTable(6,k) = 1
    ParamTable = BOMTable
End Function
```

But I have error at line "MsgBox val1(i)": "Subscript out of range".
What did I miss?
And maybe exists more simple way to transfer array from Function to main Sub when Function fill from sub-Sub?

Comment: If `val1` is a two dimensional array, what do you expect to find in `val1(0)`. You haven't specified your second dimension.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, you right! Thank you! But now array at "MsgBox" is empty. Apparently I'm transferring data incorrectly between Function and Sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I have a solution
This code works:

```
Dim PartNumber, Name, Material, Texture, Color, Quantity, k
Dim BOMTable(6,1000)

Sub CATMain()
    Dim val1
    Call WalkDownTree()
    val1 = ParamTable(PartNumber, Name, Material, Texture, Color, Quantity, k)
    For i = 1 To UBound(val1, 1)
        For j = 1 To k-1
        MsgBox val1(i,j)
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Sub WalkDownTree()
    For k = 1 To 3
        PartNumber = "PartNumber" & k
        Name = "Name" & k
        Material = "Material" & k
        Texture = "Texture" & k
        Color = "Color" & k
        Quantity = 1
        Call ParamTable(PartNumber, Name, Material, Texture, Color, Quantity, k)
    Next
End Sub

Function ParamTable(PartNumber, Name, Material, Texture, Color, Quantity, k)
    BOMTable(1,k) = PartNumber 
    BOMTable(2,k) = Name
    BOMTable(3,k) = Material
    BOMTable(4,k) = Texture
    BOMTable(5,k) = Color
    BOMTable(6,k) = Quantity
    ParamTable = BOMTable
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest not to be slacking in declaration of variables and even if it's not necessary for functioning. It is necessary for understanding.

The main global variable which holds all data should be declared on top

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim BOMData() As Variant
```

Then write the CATMain()

```vb
Sub CATMain()

    Dim ItemCount As Integer 'This would be how many rows i will have in BOM or how many parts i will read i have to get this info from CATIA
    ReDim BOMData(0 To ItemCount - 1, 0 To 5) As Variant 'This is making the collection
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Col As Integer

    For Row = 0 To ItemCount - 1 'populate the BOM collection
       Call WalkDownTree(Row)
    Next
  
    Dim TempStr As String
    For Row = 0 To ItemCount - 1 'just write each row to msgbox
        For Col = 0 To 5
            TempStr = TempStr & BOMData(Row, Col) & " "
        Next
        Call MsgBox(TempStr)
        TempStr=""
    Next

End Sub
```

This is how could look the sub which populates the collection ... you are iterating through row or that could be items (products, parts etc)

```vb
Sub WalkDownTree(Row As Integer)

    BOMData(Row, 0) = "PartNumber"
    BOMData(Row, 1) = "Name"
    BOMData(Row, 2) = "Material"
    BOMData(Row, 3) = "Texture"
    BOMData(Row, 4) = "Color"
    BOMData(Row, 5) = 1

End Sub
```

The advantage of this solution could bring you simple excel export like this

```vb
Sub WriteToExcel()

    Dim ExlApp As Excel.Application
    Set ExlApp = GetObject(, "EXCEL.Application")
    
    Dim ExlWorkBook As Workbook
    Set ExlWorkBook = ExlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xls")
    
    Dim ExlSheet As Worksheet
    Set ExlSheet = ExlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    ExlSheet.Range("A1").Resize((UBound(BOMData, 1) - LBound(BOMData, 1) + 1), (UBound(BOMData, 2) - LBound(BOMData, 2) + 1)).Value = BOMData

End Sub
```

EDIT

This is VBScript version. However i would suggest using VBA or VB .Net language for Catia if you want to seriously develop something. Using VBScript if not necessary is just torturing yourself

```vb
    Dim BOMData()
    Sub CATMain()

    Dim ItemCount 
    ItemCount = 10 'how many items you have
    ReDim BOMData (ItemCount - 1, 5) 
    Dim Row 
    Dim Col 

    For Row = 0 To ItemCount - 1 'populate the BOM collection
       Call WalkDownTree(Row)
    Next
  
    Dim TempStr
    For Row = 0 To ItemCount - 1 'just write each row to msgbox
        For Col = 0 To 5
            TempStr = TempStr & BOMData(Row, Col) & " "
        Next
        Call MsgBox(TempStr)
        TempStr=""
    Next

    End Sub
    
    Sub WalkDownTree(Row)

    BOMData(Row, 0) = "PartNumber"
    BOMData(Row, 1) = "Name"
    BOMData(Row, 2) = "Material"
    BOMData(Row, 3) = "Texture"
    BOMData(Row, 4) = "Color"
    BOMData(Row, 5) = 1

    End Sub
```

Comment: The question was about VBscript, not VBA. Your code is not valid VBScript.

Comment: I have a solution. Just see my last comment.

Comment: @Geert Bellekens true, i didn't notice vbscript tag ...